# Converting Vegur to be used for font-face

Tags: css, font-face

I need to use [Vegur](http://www.fontspace.com/arro/vegur) font, which is available in otf format, for a website. However, when I try to convert it using font squirrel or any other similar font-face generator (e.g. http://fontface.codeandmore.com/) font immediately loses all smoothness and quality...

Is anyone aware of where I could get a pre-converted version of the font? Or what else could I use to convert the font.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this page with html characters rather than the one you've linked to (that has images)?

http://www.fontspace.com/arro/vegur/22551.charmap

My OS is windowsXP (using Chrome at the moment) and XP notoriously renders non default fonts with poor quality and no smoothness. On the page you've linked to, the font looks nice and smooth because is just an image, while when I check the link above, all chars render poorly... what's your OS?